# is viewDidDisappear on the main thread?

Tags: swift, viewcontroller

When viewDidDisappear is called in the normal view lifecycle is it safe to perform UX related items?

Said another way, should I be checking if I am on the main thread prior?

Answer (score 1):

Unless the view controller is dismissed from the wrong thread, the view life-cycle methods will be called from the main thread.

Comment: Can view controller be dismissed from a thread which is not main?

Comment: It shouldn't be.